# Como é que mudo a reserva dos lugares em mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Usei [jQuery-Seat-Charts](https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts) para fazer um layout e a reserva de lugares, o problema é que quando está em mobile eu queria de outra forma.

Em desktop está assim:

```
 map: [
          'a[,4]a[,8]a[,12]a[,16]a[,20]a[,24]a[,28]a[,32]a[,36]a[,40]a[,44]a[,48]a[,53]',
          'a[,3]a[,7]a[,11]a[,15]a[,19]a[,23]a[,27]a[,31]a[,35]a[,39]a[,43]a[,47]a[,52]',
          '____________a[,51]',
          'a[,2]a[,6]a[,10]a[,14]a[,18]a[,22]a[,26]a[,30]a[,34]a[,38]a[,42]a[,46]a[,50]',
          'a[,1]a[,5]a[,9]a[,13]a[,17]a[,21]a[,25]a[,29]a[,33]a[,37]a[,41]a[,45]a[,49]',
        ],
```

E em mobile quero assim:

```
 map:[
          'aa_aa',
          'aa_aa',
          'aa_aa',
          'aa_aa',
          'aa_aa',
          'aa_aa',
          'aa_aa',
          'aa_aa',
          'aa_aa',
          'aaaaa',
        ],
```

Neste momento está assim para mobile e desktop:
[image: Desktop e mobile]
E eu quero que fique assim em mobile:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O link que colocou parece não estar a funcionar e a logica do que pretende fazer não ficou de todo clara. Comece por explicar qual a lógica de transformação e dê exemplos mais específicos. Para mim não está claro como chega do inicial ao final.

Comment: @Isac Fiz update à pergunta e ao link espero ter sido mais especifico :)

Comment: confuso o que você quer fazer, mas se quer mudar o `javascript` de acordo com mobile ou não, você deveria testar `navigator.userAgent`, veja em exemplo nessa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/4730201

Comment: Se bem percebi a forma como esse plugin funciona, o seu exemplo final não está coerente com o primeiro, pois não indica explicitamente cada um dos numeros dos lugares, como fez no primeiro. Comece por atualizar essa parte para ficar claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está a tentar fazer é basicamente transpor um array 2D. O problema é que no seu caso ainda nem sequer é um array 2D mas sim um array de `strings` o que acresce dificuldade ao problema.

Para alem disso a exemplo de saída que tem não joga com a entrada, pois a entrada tem os números dos lugares com `a[,1]`, `a[,2]` e na saída já não tem essa discriminação ficando apenas `aa`.

Coloco aqui uma solução simplificada que serve para o que tem, mas que poderá ter que ajustar mediante as informações que utiliza.  Ainda assim já deve dar uma ideia de como abordar o problema. A saída será na mesma com os lugares assim como tem na entrada.

```js
const lugares = [
      'a[,4]a[,8]a[,12]a[,16]a[,20]a[,24]a[,28]a[,32]a[,36]a[,40]a[,44]a[,48]a[,53]',
      'a[,3]a[,7]a[,11]a[,15]a[,19]a[,23]a[,27]a[,31]a[,35]a[,39]a[,43]a[,47]a[,52]',
      '____________a[,51]',
      'a[,2]a[,6]a[,10]a[,14]a[,18]a[,22]a[,26]a[,30]a[,34]a[,38]a[,42]a[,46]a[,50]',
      'a[,1]a[,5]a[,9]a[,13]a[,17]a[,21]a[,25]a[,29]a[,33]a[,37]a[,41]a[,45]a[,49]',
    ];

const divisores = {'a':true , '_':true};

//colocar espaços antes de 'a' e '_' para de seguida transformar em 2D
let lug2d = lugares.map(fila => fila.split('').
  map((letra, pos) => (pos != 0 && letra in divisores) ? ' '+letra : letra).join(''));

//transformar em 2d à custa de split pelos espaços colocados previamente
lug2d = lug2d.map(fila => fila.split(' '));

//criar o array 2d final para a transposição
let lug2dTransposto = [];
for (let i = 0; i < lug2d[0].length; ++i){
  lug2dTransposto.push([]);
}

//transpor
for(let i = lug2d.length - 1; i >=0 ; --i){
    for(let j = 0; j < lug2d[i].length ; ++j){
        lug2dTransposto[j].push(lug2d[i][j]);
    }
}

//retransformar do array 2d para array de strings
let lugFinal = lug2dTransposto.map(fila => fila.join(''));
console.log(lugFinal);
```